# Overriding the current data while binding in angular

Tags: angular

How to bind data in angular after filtering. In my case my current state got overwrite when I am applying filter in dropdown list. What I need is when I am searching from dropdown and removing the search txt from input Box then why already selecting elements got blank.

```
searchData(event:any){
  this.inputValue = event.target.value;

  if(this.inputValue.length == null){
    return this.data;
  } else {
    this.inputValue = event.target.value ?event.target.value.toLowerCase() : '';
    this.data = this.dataTemp.filter(s => {
      let userName = s.name.toLowerCase();
      return userName.indexOf(this.inputValue) > -1;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Put up the rest of your code including the html so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Seems like you're modifying your `data` value during the search and use it to display in html. However, this way you lose your original values. Quick fix would be to have `originalData` with values of your current `data`, and `modifiedData` that will be used in modifications inside your `searchData()`. Then you just display in html from `modifiedData` and if `inputValue.length == null` (or rather: if `inputValue.length == 0`) you return `originalData`.